# How would I define a custom way to combine vertices?

Tags: c++, sfml

I made a custom class to draw a 9-patch in SFML, but I think it could be optimized more.

Currently, I calculate all the vertices needed to make the 9 rectangles, and then I use some loops to add them to 9 separate quads using `sf::VertexArray`, using `sf::Quads` as `PrimitiveType`.

That's a total of 4 x 9 = 36 vertices, while it *should* be possible with only 4 x 4 = 16 vertices, *if* it's possible to define custom ways to 'link' vertices.

`sf::Triangles` groups every three vertices together. `sf::Quads` groups every four vertices together and makes two triangles out of each group. `sf::TrianglesFan` groups every two vertices together to make a triangle with the center point.

My question is, can I define a custom way to combine the vertices together so I only have to store 16 vertices?
Also, is it actually worth optimising this much, or will the difference be unnoticeable?

Comment: Do you need to apply a texture on your quads? If yes, then I think it would not be easy to assign the proper texture coordinates to grouped quads, since the next quad takes the last two vertices of the previous one. If you are using a repeatable texture (where horizontal or vert mirroring doesn't matter) or no texture at all, then you can achieve the same result by using `sf::TrianglesStrip` as explained [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-vertex-array.php)

Comment: Just another remark: If you are trying to set up your patch on a grid (3x3) then even a Quads-Strip would fail. At least it's not clear to me how you would set up the vertices so that going from one row to the next would not mess up the shape.

Comment: Since it's a 9-patch, yes, it needs a texture.

Comment: Ok just looked up "9-patch" on google. Didn't know what it means until now ;). Still, I think you better stay with `sf::Quads`

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, there is no feasable way to implement a "9-patch" with grouped Quads.

For textured shapes grouped Quads make only sense to draw seamless(repeatable) textures in a row or column. For this purpose one ca also use `sf::TriangleStrip`